# How to configure Dapr Actors to support specific State?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-container-apps, dapr

I am exploring the use of `Dapr` in my `Azure Container App`.

**Context**

I have configured a couple of actors and I am looking how I could configure different Azure Storage Accounts to save the States.

First, I have defined 2 `Dapr` components in the `Azure App Container Environment`:

[image: Azure Container App Environment]

Then I can confirm the components are available to my `Azure Container App`:

[image: Azure Container App]

Now, following the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/dapr-for-net-developers/actors#state-persistence), I need to set the metadata `actorStateStore` to `true` on the component to allow it to be used as state storage for the actors.

**Problem**

When I access the `StateManager` in my `Actor`, I do not see how I can tell `Dapr` which State Component to use (since I have defined 2) (something possible with Orleans Framework).

For instance:

```
internal interface IUserCodeActor : IActor
{
    Task CreateAsync
    (
        UserCodeContract userCodeContract
    );
}

internal sealed class UserCodeActor : Actor, IUserCodeActor
{
    private const string DefaultStateName = "user_code_state";
    
    public UserCodeActor(ActorHost actorHost) : base(actorHost)
    {
    }

    public async Task CreateAsync
    (
        UserCodeContract userCodeContract
    )
    {
        //  --> Which Storage Is Used? Can I select it?
        await StateManager.SetStateAsync
        (
            DefaultStateName,
            new UserCodeState
            {
                UserCode = userCodeContract.UserCode.Value,
                ClientId = userCodeContract.ClientId.Value,
                DeviceCode = userCodeContract.DeviceCode.Value
            }
        );

        await StateManager.SaveStateAsync();
    }
}
```

**Question**

How do I configure which `State Component` to use for a given `Actor`?